# Trying to create a fragment class

Tags: java, android, class, android-fragments

I'm trying to create a fragment class following from [this:](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

And they give you the code for a fragment class, but I'm getting

ExampleFragments.java

```
package com.example.learn.fragments;

public static class ExampleFragments extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.blue_pill_frag, container, false);
    }
}
```

But I'm getting an error on line 9, where I declare the name of the class.

```
Illegal modifier for the class ExampleFragments; only public, abstract & final are permitted
```

I'm sure it's something basic that I'm not understanding, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have a `static` top-level class. Change

```
public static class ExampleFragments extends Fragment {
```

to

```
public class ExampleFragments extends Fragment {
```

Comment: Alright, so I need to go read up on what a static class is. Thanks. Another question though. Why does google give a `static class` as an example? Should I use fragments as a static or it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's probably because it's an *inner* class.

Answer (score 1):

In the example you're following, the static modifier is used because the Fragment is a nested class.

To get rid of the error you can include that fragment into an existing class, or remove the static modifier.

Comment: Hmm... Any good examples on nested classes? The term is new to me. I've always thought that there were just classes. Thanks I appreciate the help.